# number theory. best approximation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am learning number theory.

Find all the best approximations to 339/62.

the question means that finding irrational number approximating to 339/62?

and.....what should I do?

Comment: This is not clear.  Continued fractions are used to find good rational approximations to irrationals, not the other way round.

Comment: Continued fractions (i.e. the Euclidean algorithm) are also applied for finding rational approximations to rationals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The continued fraction expansion is:

$$\frac{339}{62} = 5 + \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{4}}}.$$

The problem probably wants the "convergents" of this fraction:

$$5, 5+\frac{1}{2}, 5+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{7}}, 5 + \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{4}}}, $$

which simplify to $5, \frac{11}{2}, \frac{82}{15}, \frac{339}{62}.$  To see how close they are, the decimals are

$$ 5, 5.5, 5.4666\ldots ,5.467741935\ldots$$